Does a service panel need a metal cover?
A previous question asks if a service panel is up to code without a door. The answer was that it can be without a door (breaker handles exposed) but it cannot be without a cover for the wires.
Question: does the cover need to be metal? I have a service panel for which someone removed the metal cover and replaced it with clear plexiglass. Then they made a wooden door.


Answers to the previous question indicate that a door is not required by NEC. That means the requirement was by a local institution. Only they would have an answer to this question.

I agree with Michael.  The panel is installed outside the manufacturers' specifications, therefore it is modified in a manor not previously approved by the NEC...so not compliant

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact What on earth does that have to do with NEC/UL regulated residential electrical panels? Nothing. Comments are for requesting clarification, not tangential anecdotes. This is not a forum.

It has everything to do with "plexiglass has its place when dealing with electrical on a temporary basis but not as a permanent installation".

If you're asking what the NEC says, I believe there's nothing specifying the material used. But my understanding the most recent version requires manufacturers to provide a panel cover. Generally speaking, equipment must be installed in the manner recommended by the manufacturer, so this would likely be an issue.
Whether or not it's actually a safety issue is a separate question (but somewhat irrelevant if it's a code violation).
